# Splunk: Calculate TopN hosts but add to that TopN based on a key=value pair

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

Is there a way to get a Top Hosts count and add to each hosts count using a value from a k/v pair in the event itself?

Example:

```
<158>Mar 26 15:01:36 m500 admd SSO: write 35 bytes on fd(11) OK repeatCount=300 source =    tcp:514 sourcetype =    generic_single_line
```

So this would come up as `300` in the count of events for that host.

I'm new to Splunk so not very familiar with the query language. I tried

```
| metasearch index=* | eval Date=strftime(_time,"%Y-%m-%d") | chart count over host by Date
```

But I don't know how to add the count from that k/v

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a [splunk board](https://answers.splunk.com/answers/736656/calculate-topn-hosts-but-add-to-that-topn-based-on.html) like stackoverflow and posted there. For the sake of completeness, I'll post the solution here:

> Give this a try (I would strongly suggest to replace `index=*` with some specific index/sourcetype/source query)

```
index=* | eval Date=strftime(_time,"%Y-%m-%d") | stats count sum(repeatCount) as repeatCount by host Date | eval total=count + repeatCount | chart max(total) over host by date
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear what you are asking, do you have a better example?

You could try
`| chart sum(repeatCount) over host by Date`

Or
`| chart values(repeatCount) over host by Date`

Our a combination of one of those and count, and then an additional eval to sum those. Again, the question isn't clear, but perhaps these will point you in the right direction